# Fibonacci Number modulo m

Tags: c++

Task: Given two integers n and m, output Fn mod m (they is, the remainder of Fn when divided by m).

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

long long get_pisano_period(long long m)
{
    long long a = 0, b = 1, c;
    for (int i = 0; i < m * m; i++)
    {
        c = (a + b) % m;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        if (a == 0 && b == 1)
            return i + 1;
    }
}

long long calc_fib(long long n)
{
    vector<long long> nums(n + 1);
    nums.at(0) = 0;
    nums.at(1) = 1;
    for (long long i = 2; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        nums.at(i) = nums.at(i - 1) + nums.at(i - 2);
    }
    return nums.at(n);
}

long long solve(long long n, long long m)
{
    long long r = n % get_pisano_period(m);
    return (calc_fib(r) % m);
}

int main()
{
    long long n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    cout << solve(n, m) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My code is working for some cases(small numbers). Can anyone suggest to me, What changes should I make to run this?

```
Input:
239
1000

Output:
-191
```

You can see I am supposed to get 161 as output.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `i` in `get_pisano_period` should be a `long long`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Tried that, But didn't work.

Comment: using a bigger type will just shift the problem. Do the maths first. Modulo is distributive, ie `(a + b) mod n = [(a mod n) + (b mod n)] mod n`. You never need to store a number bigger than `2*m` in your code

Comment: @idclev463035818 Are you suggesting me to make **i  <  2*n** in function **get_pisano_period** ?

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to actually compute the modulo without iteration. It may just be delusion. EDIT: I don't mean by using the phi formula, by sheer properties of modulus and the series.

Comment: Given your question, I don't understand, why you are calculating the Pisano period at all. Don't you simply want `calc_fib(n) % m`?

Comment: @Tfry We can but only for small numbers. It will take years for bigger numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried what @idclev463035818 said and this seems to work.
Try it,

```
# include <iostream>
# include <vector>

using namespace std;

long long get_pisano_period(long long m)

{
    long long a = 0, b = 1, c;
    for (long long i = 0; i < m * m; i++)
    {
        c = (a + b) % m;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        if (a == 0 && b == 1)
            return i + 1;
    }
}

long long calc_fib(long long n, long long m)
{
    vector<long long> nums(n + 1);
    nums.at(0) = 0;
    nums.at(1) = 1;
    long long maximum = get_pisano_period(m);
    for (long long i = 2; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        nums.at(i) = (nums.at(i - 1)%m + nums.at(i - 2)%m)%m;
    }
    return nums.at(n);
}

int main()
{
    long long n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    cout << calc_fib(n, m) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```